# VS 2013 fails to specialize function template with universal reference and return type depending on template parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, universal-reference

VS 2013 says that it cannot specialize the function template in the following code:

```
struct W { };

template <class T>
typename T::result_type
f (const W & w, T && t) {
    return 0;
}

/* ... */
struct V { typedef int result_type; };

W w {};
V v {};
f (w, v);
```

If I replace `typename T::result_type` by `int` or if I replace the universal reference `T&&` by `T&`, it does not complain.

In my opinion, the above code is correct. Is this a compiler bug, or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is right. The way forwarding references<sup>(1)</sup> work is that if passed an lvalue of type `U`, they use `U&` instead of `U` for type deduction. Since `v` in your case is an lvalue, `T` is deduced to `V&`. `V&` is a reference type, it doesn't have a nested type (it cannot even have one).

When working with forwarding references, you have to always use `std::remove_reference` to get at the underlying type:

```
template <class T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type::result_type
f (const W & w, T && t) {
    return 0;
}
```

---

(1) Since CppCon 2014, "forwarding reference" was accepted as replacement term for "universal reference," since it captures the intent better.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would never have thought of this myself. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.